# Enterprise Layering: Is checking an existing account considered as business logic?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am doing a simple Log-in feature using Java EE with enterprise(? [controller-service-dao]) layering.

Should I put the code where I fetch a user from my UserService and make a decision where page it will then go in the LoginController or LoginService?

If it's in the controller, it will be neater since I can just do an if-else on User existence, then go different page depending on the result.

But if it will be in service layer, I have to make the service throw an exception (UserNotFoundException) then make the calling-controller catch then do the redirection. It seems messy and unnecessary.

What is the best approach here?

I am reading about what is considered as business logic, but I can't find anything if a simple and trivial such as Login checker, where do these kind of things categorized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a business logic and should be inside your service layer.

Also, you need NOT throw an `UserNotFoundException` just to check if `User` exists or not, if you throw exceptions like this, your application logs will be flooded with lots of exceptions unnecessarily (it will make it harder to debug the valid exceptions). Adding to that, the exception has to be thrown here or not is opinion based and should be in line with the business decision.

The solution can be to simply **create a reusable service method like `public boolean checkIfUserExists(String userId)`** which returns `true` (if the `User` exists) or `false` (if not) inside your `UserService` and call that method from the controller.

Also, one more point is in order to not to loose the data on the user login attempt failures i.e., to track the userid/other details (for future), you can simply log those details at appropriate logging level.

Comment: So it is considered as business logic? Even though it is trivial?

Comment: Why it is trivial ? It is important and is part of the business logic to validate whether duplicate user names (or whatever field) are allowed or not

Comment: @shepard23 Yes, its business-logic because its a business-decision if we like to use a users-database from another company, a business-decision if we like to send unauthorized spam, its a business-decision if we allow a buy-now-register-later mechanism and so on.

Comment: Understood, thanks guys